# Node JS "Importing binding name 'default' cannot be resolved by star export entries" for HLS.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, hls.js

Currently I have the following folder layouts in node JS and installed express js

```
sdk-components
    --- HlsLoader.js

node_modules
    --- hls.js
        --- src
            --- index.html 
            --- index.js 
        --- dist
            --- hls.js
            --- other files
```

When I load index.html in localhost like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/src/index.html
```

It calls index.js which contains:

```
import { hlsLoaderType, makeHlsLoader } from '../sdk-components/HlsLoader.js';
```

The first line of HlsLoader.js contains:

```
import Hls from 'hls.js';
```

However when I run index.html I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: Module specifier, 'hls.js' does not start with "/", "./", or "../"
```

But when I modify the import to:

```
import Hls from '../node_modules/hls.js/dist/hls.js';
```

I get this error instead:

```
SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'default' cannot be resolved by star export entries.
```

So my question is, how can I resolve this import issue for the hls.js file?

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The error basically means that the stuff from 'hls.js' was supposed to be imported as `import * as Hls from 'hls.js'`

Answer (score 0):

I just got this message myself using vanilla JS. (How I found this thread).

The 1st issue that you're having: "TypeError: Module specifier," means that when you import the file, it needs to be specified as a module.

When I import the files into my html doc, I've specified that the file has a type of module:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="./data.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <title>Module List</title>
</head>
```

That should clear that error...

Next onto the import:
**2 things I always check with ES6 module imports / exports:**

**1st** (also irrelevant to your Question): check that the extension .js is included in the import. (For some reason I see in demos that others get away without including it but for me it always seems the extension is important. 
**2nd:** is checking that what you're trying to bring in is being brought in the right format. (forgive me if I'm not using the correct lingo right now. I'm a student too.

The solution to my issue was that it was an object and I was bringing it in as a function - without curly brackets. I just needed to place brackets around it and the same error disappeared and the data came in as expected:

**// data.js file**

```
export const inverterManData = [
    { manufacturer: 'enphase', value: 'enphase' },
    { manufacturer: 'SMA', value: 'SMA' }
]
```

**// index.js file**

```
import { inverterManData } from './data.js'

console.log(inverterManData)
```

**Result:**

```
console: [{manufacturer: "enphase", value: "enphase"}, {manufacturer: "SMA", value: "SMA"}] (2)
```

...and if you remove the curly brackets notice it will cause that error again.

Hope this helps!